# Get text to a string from XML file

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a xml file and I want to take a text ('aaa') from the number tag to a string. It looks like this:

`<header_xml>
    <number>aaa</number>
</header_xml>`

I tried to use methods found in the Internet but they doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
sGeneratorPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) ' --- Open FileDialog
    .InitialFileName = sGeneratorPath ' --- inital path
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "XML Files (*.xml)", "*.xml" ' --- add filter to choose only xml files
    .AllowMultiSelect = False ' --- to select only one file

    If .Show = False Then ' --- if operation aborted, display message
        MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
        End
    End If

    sXMLPath = .SelectedItems(1) ' --- path of xml file
End With

oXMLFile.Load (sXMLPath)

Set HWNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/header_xml/number/")
sHWID = HWNode.Text
MsgBox sHWID

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Creating this ProgID - `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`  - is now obsolete. Use `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` instead - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close.  Just remove the extra `/` after `number`

```
Set HWNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/header_xml/number")
```

**Tested**

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I was trying everyting by almost 2 hours and didn't see that. Thank you very much!